# Use cases of the "Release Event" on a smart switch

Tags: smart-home, zwave, domoticz

I have a [Nodon Z-Wave remote](http://nodon.fr/en/z-wave/z-wave-soft-remote_8-2) ([user guide](http://www.vesternet.com/downloads/dl/file/id/806/product/1713/z_wave_nodon_soft_remote_user_guide.pdf)). It has 4 buttons which can react to 4 events :

- Single press
- Double press
- Long press
- Release

The three first are pretty straightforward. But the "release" part is very particular : **it will always fire after any press action!**

On [Domoticz](https://domoticz.com/), the only way to register this release action is to push the button, then activate the button detection feature, or else it will detect the press action before and say it is already registered.

Apart from automatic blinds/shades I don't know how I can use this feature since it is always linked to a press action, especially a long press because we need to maintain the button and release it.

Have you ever found any uses for release scenarios or is it only specific for this model (i.e. other devices don't send the "press" event)?

Comment: I'm not sure what 'automatic stores/shades' are - are you describing [this kind of thing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HHgbrfvR7UQ&feature=youtu.be&t=45s)?

Comment: I guess the OP means "device(s) has dimming features (light dimmer, roller shutter, etc.)" (From User guide) by stores/shades.

Comment: Yes it is blinds! I'm french and "store" is how we translate it.

Answer (score 8):

The `release` event is more likely intended to be used as a pair with the `press` event, allowing you to indicate a duration. My dimmable lightwave-rf lamp control overloads up/down buttons as both on/off, and increase/decrease brightness.

A short press is identified as a switch action, a long press starts a increment/decrement process which is ended by the release action.

I have not monitored the transmission to confirm if it is the lamp or the remote control which performs the increment/decrement, but implementing this logic at the lamp reduces the number of codes which need to be transmitted (and is more generic).

Presumably, the codes for these 4 actions can be computed knowing the code for any one, in the form `nnnnaa` (`aa` encoding the 4 actions for one of 16 buttons).

Comment: I checked on my swich, the release case works only after the long press event. The problem is that it takes 1 second to "trigger", I don't know how long does your dimmer reacts to the long press (instant?). I am waiting for other use cases before validating the answer.

Comment: no, there is roughly a 1 sec delay before it starts to dim, its short press for off (and not change the set level), or press and hold to adjust the level.